# Node.Js Map example, adding speed and on-click data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapbox

I've been attempting to learn better visualization with node.js and the mapbox library.

Using this example here: [Running Map Example](https://github.com/mapbox/running-map-example)

I'd like to add a graph of speed, and allow a user to click on a node, and see data about that position in a little popup - For today, I just want to get speed working.

It seems to be a recursive algorithm, so I need to implement variables to store the previous position and time, but I've ran into three problems:

- I don't know how to use this date format: "2015-01-19T21:24:20Z" or Chroniton's parsing of it to generate a subtractable number to get the difference in time.
- I don't know how to get the distance between two points using the code given, I could simply do `sqrt((.x(point1) - .x(point2)) + (.y(point1) + .y(point2))`, but I'm not sure how coordinates are stored or parsed in this example.
- I don't know *where* to calculate the speed. It seems like the coordinates are only defined after the graphs are displayed, since the coordinates aren't used in the graphics. I am probably wrong, but I need some direction.

Here is what I have now:
Using the elevation display as my template, I *think* I have made it able to display the line by adding in the following three snippets:

Setting the scale:

```
var speed = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0])
.domain([0, d3.max(dataRet, function(d) {
    return d[1][2];
})]);
```

Adding in the line, with data:

```
var SpeedLine = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .y(function (d) { return speed(d[2])})
```

Displaying the line:

```
svg.append('path')
.datum(dataRet)
.attr('class', 'speed-line')
.attr('d', speedLine);
```

I know I have to add in a speed function similar to this psudocode:

```
var dt = chroniton.domain(Time1, Time2)
var speed[i] = LongLat(previousPoint).distanceto(currentPoint)/dt
```

And on the popup box:

```
dt.format(something to do with time formatting)
```

Note 1:, I changed the name of the function `datePlaceHeart` to `dataRet` since I'll be adding new things to do it, and `datePlaceHeartSpeedStuffAndThings` was getting a bit long ;)

Note 2: I haven't been able to start the pop-up because I haven't figured out how to calculate speed using the given data, and well, it seems kinda silly to do the easy one first. (With my luck, its actually not easy)

Please help? Here is my edited code in full (Edited index.js):
[Code](http://pastebin.com/Qs2HTZni)

Comment: You are lumping a lot of problems into a single question, so you're not likely to get much activity.  Isolate a minimal example of each problem you are having and ask separate questions.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: There is really only one problem: I don't know how to get speed to display.

The box is optional, and only brought up at the beginning. I can remove it if you think that would be best, but if someone could point me in the right direction, it would be more valuable that just speed alone.

This is really only one step above a completely minimumal example, and I wouldn't go lower or otherwise I'd have people asking why I'm using chroniton and Mapbox, and showing solutions without it.

(This happens to me often on SO)